# Unclassing only categorical variables in R

Tags: r

I have a df like so in R

```
isHot isCrispy Restaurant
1     0        A
0     0        B
1     1        B
0     0        C
```

I want the dataset to look like this:

```
isHot isCrispy Restaurant
1     0        0
0     0        1
1     1        1
0     0        2
```

How can I do this?

I tried this but I get something that starts at 0 instead of 1. If i subtract 1 than the other columns become 0 and -1.

```
df %>% sapply(unclass)
```

```
isHot isCrispy Restaurant
1     0        1
0     0        2
1     1        2
0     0        3
```

Comment: Are these values only based on `Restaurant` column ? How about `match(df$Restaurant, unique(df$Restaurant)) - 1` ?

Comment: I want to do this dynamically though. Its based on any column that is categorical/factor

Comment: @Eisen you should edit your question to include relevant details like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `across` you can apply a function to all character or factor columns. `match` + `unique` would give a unique number to every value, `-1` would ensure that they start from 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~is.character(.) | is.factor(.)), 
        ~match(., unique(.)) - 1))

#  isHot isCrispy Restaurant
#1     1        0          0
#2     0        0          1
#3     1        1          1
#4     0        0          2
```

Comment: What does the dot (.) argument mean?

Comment: It is an alternative to use an anonymous where `.` refers to the values in the individual column.

Answer (score 1):

Factors can be easily transformed to numbers according to their position in their levels (alphabetically sorted by default):

```r
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
  ~isHot, ~isCrispy, ~Restaurant,
  1, 0, "A",
  0, 0, "B",
  1, 1, "B",
  0, 0, "C"
) %>%
  mutate(Restaurant = Restaurant %>% as.factor()) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, ~ .x %>% as.numeric() - 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   isHot isCrispy Restaurant
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1        0          0
#> 2     0        0          1
#> 3     1        1          1
#> 4     0        0          2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `mutate_if` is outdated nowadays and has been superseded by `mutate` + `across()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (base R):

```r
isfac <- sapply(dat, inherits, c("character", "factor"))
dat[isfac] <- lapply(dat[isfac], function(z) match(z, unique(z)) - 1)
dat
#   isHot isCrispy Restaurant Restaurant_fctr
# 1     1        0          0               0
# 2     0        0          1               1
# 3     1        1          1               1
# 4     0        0          2               2
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(isHot = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), isCrispy = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Restaurant = c("A", "B", "B", "C"), Restaurant_fctr = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ isHot          : int  1 0 1 0
#  $ isCrispy       : int  0 0 1 0
#  $ Restaurant     : chr  "A" "B" "B" "C"
#  $ Restaurant_fctr: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 2 3
```